# Lower bounds for the function $y =(e^{x-\alpha}-1)(x-\alpha)$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the function $y =(e^{x-\alpha}-1)(x-\alpha)$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I need and estimate such as
$$(e^{x-\alpha}-1)(x-\alpha)\ge c (e^x-1)(x-\alpha)$$
or also
$$(e^{x-\alpha}-1)(x-\alpha)\ge c (e^{x-\alpha}-1)x$$
for some positive constants $c$.
I am in trouble to prove that at least one of these inequalities hold true.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've not looked, but it's likely a few rounds of differentiation will solve your problem. It often does for simple functions as these

Answer (score 0):

Where is the function defined? If it is defined on $x\geq k$ for some $k>\alpha$, then the second inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{x-\alpha}x\ge c$$
or
$$1-\frac \alpha x\geq c$$
which is clearly true.

Or if $x>0$, then in the first inequality, just $c=1$ does the job since it translates to showing
$$\frac{e^{x-\alpha}-1}{e^{x}-1}\geq 1$$
which is of course true since $e^{x-\alpha}=\frac {e^{x}}{e^\alpha}$